# -bash: $: command not found when installing Dart package

Tags: linux, bash, path, terminal, dart

I am trying to install http://stagehand.pub.

I changed my terminal path to `:/Users/king/Desktop/dart/dart-sdk`. I checked to see if my `PATH` is changed, and run `echo $PATH` in terminal, and I got

```
green:~ king$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/king/Desktop/dart/dart-sdk
```

I type

```
$ pub global activate stagehand
```

and the output is

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

The instructions on `stagehand.pub` are simple, but I am new to this, so I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: The dollar sign is just part of the prompt, not the command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.../dart-sdk/bin` to your path.

Comment: "Last login: Mon Oct 27 06:20:47 on ttys000
green:~ king$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/king/Desktop/dart/dart-sdk/bin
green:~ king$ $ pub global activate stagehand
-bash: $: command not found"

Still doesn't work :(

Comment: `/Users/...` is probably wrong. Try it by writing the entire path explicitely like `/Users/king/Desktop/dart/dart-sdk/bin/pub` or run `sudo find / -name pub` to get the correct path.

Comment: Same error. Is there anyway else I could do this? I can go in dart editor and run pub get but it doesn't bring the templates

Comment: Without a proper path setting I see no chance.

Comment: any tutorials on setting a proper path?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Dart, you may look here http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: well the way you access dart pub is different so it has a little something to do with dart

Comment: `pub` is an executable in the `dart-sdk/bin` directory. What is there special about it?

Comment: Well it seems Dart there is something different about the pub as they release a update http://news.dartlang.org/2014/10/dart-17-easily-share-and-use-command.html  

I will go as ask the unix stack exchange thanks for your help

Comment: Dart scripts global activated by pub are a bit special, that is true but `pub` itself is not special at all in regards of calling it on command line.

Comment: @King did you re-launch bash shell?

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually type dollar sign at the start of the command as in `$ pub global activate stagehand`?
First part of the command should be `pub` as in `pub global activate stagehand`

Comment: I tried and get "-bash: pub: command not found" any tutorial on how to set up the path and to get pubs? do I need to CD a directory or pub the link? I looked on dartlang.org and it doest say how to setup your path it just assumes u know and they only give u the commands smh